# List of Generic Objects in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple class that includes 2 properties, one String and one a List of generic Objects.  It looks like this:

```
public class SessionFieldViewModel
{
    private String _name;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    private List<Object> _value;
    public List<Object> Value
    {
        get { return _value ?? new List<Object>(); }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```

Within my main code (MVC Controller) I am trying to manually populate this class.  Keep in mind that when I pass data from a webform into this class using the default model binder this get populated just fine.

When Manually trying to create a record and and add it to a list I do this:

```
        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

        var _searchField = new SessionFieldViewModel();
        _searchField.Name = "IDGUID";
        Object _object = (Object)id;
        _searchField.Value.Add(_object);

        _searchFields.Fields.Add(_searchField);
```

When I do this I do get a populated class with a Name property of "IDGUID", but the generic lists of objects comes back null.

When I debug the code and walk it though the data seems to all be there and working as I am doing it, but when I get through and inspect _searchFields it does not show anything in the Value property of Fields.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Tom
tlatourelle

Comment: Where does the generic list comes null? A model binder is used for binding values coming from an HTTP request. How does your view look like? What about the POST action? Why are you using `List<object>`? Why generics when you don't know the type at compile time? Seems kinda useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you never set `_value` when it is null from the getter. Try

```
public List<Object> Value
{
    get { return _value ?? (_value = new List<Object>()); }
    set { _value = value; }
}
```

Comment: Good catch.  I didn't see that.  Also since this code is also working through the Default Model Binder and returning actual values in another use case I didn't consider that this part would be broken.

Answer (score 2):

`_value` is never getting set to an instance of `List<Object>`; it is always null. What's happening is you are returning a new `List<Object>` and adding an `Object` to it, but you're immediately discarding the newly-created `List<Object>`.

You need to change your definition of `Value` to something like this:

```
private List<Object> _value = new List<Object>();
public List<Object> Value
{
    get { return _value; }
    set { _value = value; }
}
```